# displaying one comparison pair at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css, comparison

how can I make comparisons and then display just one pair at a time and once I've clicked on a choice it moves to the other pair

for example:

John Martin

John Sam

Martin Sam

I think I need to work with `css` and `display: none;` but i'm not sure how it goes exactly

I've defined `class="btn"` for each button for this purpose

```js
let characters = [
   {name: document.getElementById("name1").textContent, points: 0},
   {name: document.getElementById("name2").textContent, points: 0},
   {name: document.getElementById("name3").textContent, points: 0}
   ];
   
   
function choice (button) {
   const buttonCharacterObject = characters.find(obj => obj.name === button.textContent);
   buttonCharacterObject.points += 1;
   const ranking = characters.sort((a, b) => (a.points < b.points ? 1 : -1));
   console.log(ranking);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="name1" onclick="choice(this)">Martin</button>
<button class="btn" id="name2" onclick="choice(this)">Sam</button>
<button class="btn" id="name3" onclick="choice(this)">John</button>
```

Comment: You should fix this first: id 's value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.). Browsers treat non-conforming IDs that contain whitespace as if the whitespace is part of the ID. In contrast to the class attribute, which allows space-separated values, elements can only have one single ID value. --- Just change them to "name1", etc.

Comment: i'm using that ID exclusively for linking in JS, and it's working fine, do I have to write name-1 name-2 etc ?

Comment: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: okay thanks! will fix that. Any idea on how i can solve my problem ? or get close to the answer ?

Comment: Please fix the IDs first and then edit your question to show the new code. Understandably, you are very unlikely to get help when there are basic syntax errors in your code.

Comment: i did now, anything else i can do to improve the question ?

Comment: Yes. It is not clear to me what you are hoping to see. Do you want a button to disappear once clicked? And this "***how can I make comparisons and then display just one pair at a time and once I've clicked on a choice it moves to the other pair***" is unclear.

Comment: basically i have these 3 characters that i want to make comparisons with, and i want only one pair to be displayed at a time instead of all the buttons like: John Martin. Once you select one of them it moves to the other one like: John Sam or Martin Sam

Comment: So you have 3 buttons A, B, and C. I click A and then A hides leaving only B and C. Now I click B and B hides leaving only C. Or should it now show A and C (A was un-hidden)? Then this process repeats?

Comment: not really, from those 3 buttons you choose 2 to display, whatever you select takes you to other pair which you wrote in code, it doesn't hide the choice you selected, it just moves to the next pairs that you have in code, for example: `["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["c", "b"]`

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I'm being a bit obtuse, but I'm not following you. Would you please edit your question to illustrate what you're looking for? Maybe show a graphic representation.

Comment: i don't know how to do it, but the best example i can give you is in a website called "sorta.app" pick any list and i think you will get it